# How can I do subject clustering in a high dimension?

Tags: clustering, high-dimensional

I am working on a dataset with 200 participants' data. For each participant, we collected 20-70 days' data. After data engineering, we got features over 300 dimensions. Do we have any way to cluster the participants based on the features?

In the current stage, I calculate the average value of each participant's features. For example, if we have 30 days' data from one participant, I would calculate the average value of these 30 days' data across features.
Then, the problem becomes doing clustering based on 200 sample points with 300 dimensions of features. I applied PCA and reduce the dimension to 90 (95% as the variance ratio), and tried k-means and GMM in doing clustering. However, I got the silhouette score lower than 0.1.

Is there any method I can try to improve the clustering performances? I am not sure whether it is okay to calculate the average value of each participant in the high dimension data. Also, the dimension of 90 is still high. I think the k-means and GMM may not work well in this case. Is there any clustering algorithms that can be applied in high-dimension data?

Thanks all!

Comment: Is your data normalized?  If the magnitude of a few variables are significantly different from the others it will skew the results of the clustering.

Comment: Good point, thanks! Yes, I have normalized the features include some binary features. They are all in the 0-1 range.

Comment: Have a look at NSC (Nearest Shrunken Centroids).

Comment: Have you tried the very classic hierarchical clustering? It is a good choice for small problems such as yours. But in general I'd suggest to first get rid of most features.